# Como exportar uma página HTML/PHP para PDF

Tags: php, pdf

Como exportar uma página HTML para um ficheiro PDF?

Tendo um documento padrão onde possa mudar variáveis dentro desse template para depois exportar essa página para um ficheiro PDF em formato A4, sem estragar o layout.

Exemplo de código:

```php
$conteudo_html = '
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css"/>
            <title></title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <div id="header">'.$titulo.'</div>
            <div class="left">'.$conteudo_esq.'</div>
            <div class="right">'.$conteudo_dto.'</div>
            <div id="footer">'.$rodape.'</div>
        </body>
    </html>';
```

Comment: Como só tenho link e não tenho experiência para falar, vou apenas postar o link do que já me indicaram: http://html2pdf.fr/en/default

Comment: @bigown, obrigado! Tambem estou a testar esse _html2pdf_ :) mas não sei muito sobre essa biblioteca nem sobre as funções nativas de PHP para PDFs, daí a pergunta... ◉_◉

Comment: Eu já usei a mpdf, e a fpdf, vale dar uma olhada também.

Comment: FPDF é bem simples e vem com a documentaçao que ajuda bastante

Comment: @Sergio qual usaste e porque?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Costumo utilizar uma ferramenta que se chama [DOMPDF](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf) <sup>(inglês)</sup> dompdf que é um conversor de HTML para PDF.

O que ele faz é ler o DOM da página HTML em questão e converter a mesma para um documento PDF:

Existem muitos exemplos a partir da [página deles](http://pxd.me/dompdf/www/examples.php) <sup>(inglês)</sup>, mas fica aqui um a funcionar:

**qualquerCoisa.php**

```php
<?php

/* Preparação do conteúdo
 * (costumo ter uma função a realizar esta tarefa)
 */
$html = '
<p>O meu HTML como quero ver no navegador!</p>
<p>Já formatado e com CSS.</p>';


/* Preparação do documento final
 */
$documentTemplate = '
<!doctype html> 
<html> 
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="http://www.site.com/css/style.css" type="text/css">
    </head> 
    <body>
        <div id="wrapper">
            '.$html.'
        </div>
    </body> 
</html>';


// inclusão da biblioteca
require_once("dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php");


// alguns ajustes devido a variações de servidor para servidor
if ( get_magic_quotes_gpc() )
    $documentTemplate = stripslashes($documentTemplate);


// abertura de novo documento
$dompdf = new DOMPDF();

// carregar o HTML
$dompdf->load_html($documentTemplate);

// dados do documento destino
$dompdf->set_paper("A4", "portrail");

// gerar documento destino
$dompdf->render();

// enviar documento destino para download
$dompdf->stream("dompdf_out.pdf");

exit(0);
?>
```

**Notas:**
É particularmente exigente, ou seja, HTML mal formatado vai ser ignorado.
Suporta praticamente tudo de CSS 2.1.

---

#### Resumo:

Fica aqui a versão resumida do exemplo em cima apresentado para demonstrar que é possível gerar o PDF com poucas linhas de código:

```php
<?php

$html = 'o meu HTML pronto tal como vai para o navegador!';

$documentTemplate = '
<!doctype html> 
<html> 
 <head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.example.com/style.css">
 </head> 
 <body>
  <div id="wrapper">
   '.$html.'
  </div>
 </body> 
</html>';

require_once("dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php");

if ( get_magic_quotes_gpc() )
    $documentTemplate = stripslashes($documentTemplate);

$dompdf = new DOMPDF();
$dompdf->load_html($documentTemplate);
$dompdf->set_paper("A4", "portrail");
$dompdf->render();

// enviar documento destino para download
$dompdf->stream("dompdf_out.pdf");

exit(0);

?>
```

Comment: Só tem um problema, ele rejeita um monte de tags do html5.

Comment: Será que rejeita tanto quanto o **html2pdf** ? =/

Comment: @MarcosHenzel O mais simples é fazer um teste... Pega num pedaço de HTML perfeitamente válido e usa cada uma das ferramentas que te parecem promissoras, para gerar o PDF com esse mesmo HTML. Logo verificas qual a que se comporta melhor ;)

Comment: Pois é, to testando pra ver, o bom do **html2pdf** é que ele gera **barcodes**

Comment: E se ele não der certo com este código que você postou?

Comment: @CarlosHenrique Se estiveres com dificuldade, abre uma pergunta aqui no site com o teu código que eu ou outros ajudamos a resolver. Sem ver o teu código é difícil saber o que está errado ou qualquer outra coisa que esteja a acontecer para "não dar certo". ;)

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/235720/fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o-get-magic-quotes-gpc-erro

Comment: Fala meu caro, tudo beleza ? puxo meu html via JS e mando para meu controller, porem ele não executa no pdf, e a página pdf vem em branco.

Answer (score 17):

Embora seja desejável ter uma implementação nativa desse tipo de biblioteca na linguagem que usamos, é importante considerar opções que podem ser integradas à linguagem sem grandes dificuldades.

Encontrei [este tópico](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/391005/convert-html-css-to-pdf-with-php), que cita o [**WKHTMLTOPDF**](https://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf). Não é uma biblioteca PHP, mas um programa de linha de comando que faz a conversão de `HTML`para `PDF` e pode ser integrado ao PHP como [descrito aqui](https://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/wiki/IntegrationWithPhp). Ele é baseado no *WebKit*, e há vários relatos de que o *output* é bem fiel ao original.

Existe ainda uma [extensão para o PHP](https://github.com/mreiferson/php-wkhtmltox/) e uma [implementação de mais alto nível](https://github.com/mikehaertl/phpwkhtmltopdf), que procura facilitar o uso.

Obviamente, há a questão da necessidade de acesso como *root* ao sistema operacional para fazer a instalação e configuração, nem sempre disponível em *hosts* contratados. Além disso, alguns usuários relataram dificuldades em instalar a biblioteca em algumas distribuições Linux ou determinados tipos de processadores.

Comment: A rapidez da exportação é um diferencial, visto que as outras (TCPDF, FPDF, DOMPDF, etc.) podem levar muito tempo para páginas grandes ou se houver tabelas.

Comment: Suporta `barcodes` e `CSS` ?

Answer (score 11):

Eu já faço uso do *Headless Browser* **PhantomJS** para download de páginas WEB Completas renderizadas de forma FIEL a exibida no browser comum (ele interpreta o JS e CSS) mas com ele tambem é possivel realizar um *print screen* da página desejada da sequinte forma:

- Crie um arquivo com extensão .js
- Cole e salve o seguinte conteúdo:

Comando que acessa uma determinada página e salva o conteúdo da mesma em um .png (mas pode salvar como PDF):

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.open('http://stackoverflow.com/', function() {
  page.render('stackoverflow.png');
  phantom.exit();
});
```

- chame-o da seguinte foma na linha de comandos: nome do programa (caso ele tenha sido inserido no path) mais npath do arquivo javascript criado no item acima ficando da seguinte forma:

  phantomjs teste.js

Com ele tambem é possivel estabelecer as dimensões da janela onde o site é exibido (isto é util caso queira ver como está sendo renderizado um site responsivo) da seguinte forma (esta configuração deve ser feita antes do page.open()):

```
var webPage = require('webpage');
var page = webPage.create();

page.viewportSize = {
  width: 480,
  height: 800
};
```

Você pode chama-lo usando o comando shell_exec desta forma:

```
    $pathToPhantomJS = 'C:\phantomjs-2.0.0-windows\bin\phantomjs';
    $pathToJSScript = 'GetPage.js';
    $comand = $pathToPhantomJS . ' ' . $pathToJSScript . ' ' . $site;
    shell_exec($comand);
```

Obs: passo uma terceira variavel que representa o site a ter sua pagina *printada* o site é pego pelo vetor de args que são passados para o shell.

É possivel criar um CRON JOB para executar o comando `phantomjs teste.js` em determinado horário.

O PhantomJS me foi muito util e é muito configuravel e não conseguiria descrever todas a possibilidades aqui então estou colando alguns links Oficial e não Oficias que poderão ser uteis:

**Download**

Link: http://phantomjs.org/download.html

**Documentação**

Screen Capture: [Link](http://phantomjs.org/screen-capture.html)

viewportSize: [Link](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/property/viewport-size.html)

shell_exec (PHP): [Link](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.shell-exec.php)

Comment: na minha implementação o PhantomJS executou a exportação em cerca de 2% do tempo das outras bibliotecas em PHP. Além disso a possibilidade de adicionar cabeçalho e rodapé é um diferencial.

Comment: @Sanção ele é muito bom mesmo e tem uma gama gigantesca de formas de configuração e funcionalidades (que até escrapolam o escopo desta perguta)

Answer (score 5):

Se você preferir um que reconheça propriedades CSS, recomendo o **mPDF**

Recursos:

- Aceita UTF-8
- Suporte ao CSS
- Suporta imagens JPEG, GIF, PNG, WMF e SVG
- Marca d'água
- Biblioteca PHP Standalone
- Etc...

Veja todos os recursos em http://mpdf.bpm1.com/index.php?page=Features

Download: http://www.mpdf1.com/mpdf/index.php?page=Download

Answer (score 4):

Use o [FPDF](http://www.fpdf.org/) de uma olhada em http://www.fpdf.org/ é bem interessante essa biblioteca.

Answer (score 4):

De todas as bibliotecas que eu usei, a que mais gostei foi a [TCPDF](http://www.tcpdf.org/)

Na minha opinião é a mais completa e a mais simples de usar.

Possui uma boa documentação e vários [exemplos práticos](http://www.tcpdf.org/examples.php).

Alguns dos recursos disponíveis:

- Renderizar conteúdo HTML
- Inserir Código de Barras (1D/2D)
- Trabalhar com cores CMYK
- Inserir Imagens Vetoriais (EPS/AI)
- Mover, copiar e exclui páginas

Answer (score 3):

Eu recomendo usar o html2pdf, ele apenas precisa colocar o conteúdo do HTML e a saida.

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');
    $content = "<!DOCTYPE html><html><body><h1>This is heading 1</h1>
    <h2>This is heading 2</h2><h3>This is heading 3</h3>
    <h4>This is heading 4</h4><h5>This is heading 5</h5>
    <h6>This is heading 6</h6></body></html>";

    require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'\html2pdf\html2pdf.class.php');
    $html2pdf = new HTML2PDF('P','A4','fr');
    $html2pdf->WriteHTML($content);
    $html2pdf->Output('example.pdf', 'F');

?>
```

O `$html2pdf->Output` sem `'F'` faz imprimir o PDF na tela, com grava o arquivo local sem exibi-lo. No exemplo acima o PDF é salvo no servidor, podendo ser baixado posteriormente.

Para exibir defina o output assim `$html2pdf->Output('example.pdf');`

Download disponível em http://sourceforge.net/projects/phphtml2pdf/

Exemplos http://html2pdf.fr/en/example

Answer (score 0):

Use a biblioteca [jsPDF](http://mrrio.github.io/jsPDF/).

Roda no lado client sem a necessidade de qualquer processamento no servidor. Isso não significa que você não precise de um servidor, é claro, mas torna o jsPDF **compatível com qualquer tecnologia do lado servidor**, pois você pode processar seus dados no servidor e utilizar o resultado desse processamento como fonte de dados para a geração de seus arquivos PDFs com JavaScript.