# Converter página html para imagem ou pdf?

Tags: php, html, pdf

Gostaria de gerar uma imagem ou *pdf* a partir de um arquivo *html* e enviar o arquivo por *email*, alguém sabe como posso fazer isso? Já procurei por algumas *classes*, mas não achei nenhuma ideal.

Comment: Qual linguagem está usando?

Comment: Estou usando php para gerar o arquivo html

Comment: já olhou essa [pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/714/como-exportar-uma-pagina-html-php-para-pdf) ?

Comment: Use http://www.fpdf.org/, é bem fácil trabalhar com essa classe

Answer (score 1):

Utilize [FPDF](http://www.fpdf.org/)

**Exemplo 1:**

```
<?php
require('fpdf.php');

$pdf = new FPDF();
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',16);
$pdf->Cell(40,10,'Hello World!');
$pdf->Output();
?>
```

*Refêrencia:* http://www.fpdf.org/en/tutorial/tuto1.htm

**Exemplo 2:**

```
<?php
require('fpdf.php');

class PDF extends FPDF
{
   // Page header
   function Header()
   {
       // Logo
       $this->Image('logo.png',10,6,30);
       // Arial bold 15
       $this->SetFont('Arial','B',15);
       // Move to the right
       $this->Cell(80);
       // Title
       $this->Cell(30,10,'Title',1,0,'C');
       // Line break
       $this->Ln(20);
   }

   // Page footer
   function Footer()
   {
       // Position at 1.5 cm from bottom
       $this->SetY(-15);
       // Arial italic 8
       $this->SetFont('Arial','I',8);
       // Page number
       $this->Cell(0,10,'Page '.$this->PageNo().'/{nb}',0,0,'C');
   }
}

// Instanciation of inherited class
$pdf = new PDF();
$pdf->AliasNbPages();
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('Times','',12);
for($i=1;$i<=40;$i++)
    $pdf->Cell(0,10,'Printing line number '.$i,0,1);
$pdf->Output();
?>
```

*Refêrencia:* http://www.fpdf.org/en/tutorial/tuto2.htm

> Todos os tutoriais estão no [FPDF Tutorial](http://www.fpdf.org/en/tutorial/index.php)
>
> Scripts prontos é só adequar no [FPDF Scripts](http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/index.php)

**Referência Geral:** http://www.fpdf.org/

Comment: da uma olhada nesta lib. eu já utilizei ela e realmente funciona
http://phantomjs.org/screen-capture.html