# Como gerar contrato em PDF utilizando PHP diretamente?

Tags: php, pdf

Estou precisando gerar um contrato, que virá de um formulário HTML, cujos dados serão processado por um PHP.

Preciso que no momento que o usuário clicar o botão `GerarPDF` os dados digitados pelo usuário apareçam no contrato e este contrato seja gerado em PDF.

É possível gerar o contrato completo diretamente do PHP, utilizando os dados vindos do formulário HTML?

Comment: Eu sempre utilizo o html2pdf. Com ele eu posso gerar PDF com tags HTML.

Answer (score 7):

<sup><sub>Para converter  HTML pra PDF, já temos [outra pergunta no site](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/714/), nesta mostro como gerar um PDF **diretamente do PHP**.</sub></sup>

Usando a classe **[FPDF](http://www.fpdf.org/)**, que é escrita inteiramente em PHP e liberada para uso comercial sem custo, um PDF pode ser criado do zero, sem HTML intermediário, utilizando funções bem simples para escrever e inserir elementos gráficos diretamente na página, com isto, tendo-se um controle preciso do resultado final.

Segue um exemplo bem didático, apenas com o essencial:

**gerarpdf.php**:

```
<?php 
   require_once( 'fpdf.php' );

   $nome  = @$_POST['nome'];  // Sim, a supressão @ é perfeitamente válida neste exemplo
   $horas = @$_POST['horas']; // os parâmetros serão checados logo em seguida.
   $data  = @$_POST['data'];  // Num cenário onde seja comum o envio vazio, use isset()
   // Aqui você processa os parâmetros desejados, isto é só um exemplo.
   // Utilizei as variáveis do <form>, mas aqui você pode pegar o que
   // precisar de algum DB, ou mesmo misturar as técnicas.
   if( empty( $nome  ) ) $nome = 'Anônimo da Silva';
   if( empty( $horas ) ) $horas = 24;
   if( empty( $data  ) ) $data = '17 de agosto de 2014';

   // e finalmente, geramos o PDF:
   $pdf = new FPDF();

   $pdf->AddPage();
   $pdf->SetFont('Arial','B', 14);
   $pdf->SetXY( 10, 20 );
   $pdf->Cell( 190, 0, 'DECLARAÇÃO', 0, 0, 'C');

   $pdf->SetFont('Arial','', 12);
   $pdf->SetXY( 10, 30 );
   $pdf->MultiCell( 190, 6,
      "  Eu, $nome, declaro que adquiri de Alaor Ivan Souza ".
      "um pacote de créditos para acesso à internet com duração ".
      "de $horas horas, iniciando-se em $data.\n".
      "  Declaro ainda que estas informações provavelmente são ".
      "inverídicas e sem sentido, pois isto aqui é um mero teste."
   );
   $pdf->Output(); // Isto envia o PDF diretamente para o usuário.
                   // Para gerar como arquivo use Output('F','caminho_do_arquivo.pdf') 
?>
```

**formulario.htm**:

```
<form method="post" action="gerarpdf.php">
   <label for="nome">Nome:</label><br>
   <input type="text" id="nome" name="nome"><br>
   <label for="horas">Horas:</label><br>
   <input type="text" id="horas" name="horas"><br>
   <label for="data">Data por extenso:</label><br>
   <input type="text" id="data" name="data"><br>
   <br>
   <input type="submit" value="Gerar PDF"><br>
</form>
```

Este código é apenas para dar uma noção básica de como é simples usar o FPDF, o [site oficial](http://www.fpdf.org/) tem exemplos e tutoriais bem mais completos, além de uma série de extensões para códigos de barra, desenhos, gráficos, suporte a UTF-8, inclusive detalhando como fazer o *embed* de fontes personalizadas no PDF.

### Observações importantes:

- Para a acentuação funcionar direito, você tem que setar o mesmo encoding no formulário e no PHP, e caso sejam em UTF-8, usar `utf8_decode()` ao mesclar. Isto também vale para as *strings* do código;
- a FPDF tem uma versão no próprio site, com suporte para UTF-8 se necessário;
- neste demo eu não fiz embed de nenhuma fonte, mas é bem simples de se fazer, e no site há uma série de exemplos muito bons.

Confira o manual em: http://www.fpdf.org

Comment: Segue um demo. Só pus como comment, pq esse link vai quebrar logo logo. http://ninja.net.br/fpdf_001.php?nome=Bacco&horas=120&data=7+de+Setembro+de+2014 . Para testar, copie o link e altere os parâmetros, pois o demo usa GET.

Comment: Muito Bom @Bacco Valeu pela Força Muito Obrigado!