# Como gerar um PDF a partir de um fomulário de cadastro e em seguida anexar o arquivo gerado e enviá-lo por e-mail?

Tags: php, javascript, email, pdf, jspdf

Preciso gerar um PDF ao final do preenchimento de um formulário e em seguida anexá-lo e fazer o envio por e-mail. Preciso de uma luz pois não tenho ideia de quais ferramentas utilizar!

desde já agradeço muito pela atenção.

Comment: ajuda? https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/31771/como-gerar-contrato-em-pdf-utilizando-php-diretamente?rq=1

Comment: Toda ajuda é bem vinda! Muito obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

Após o POST do formulário, monte um "body" em HTML mesmo (você não precisa exibi-lo. Guarde em uma variável), e faça a lib de PDF de sua escolha converter em um PDF válido.

Pessoalmente uso o [mPDF](https://mpdf.github.io/) para isso e resolve 95% dos meus problemas (tive um problema recente com grandes tabelas e ainda não consegui sanar. No mais, é perfeito e super flexível).

Após isso, gravo o PDF no servidor. No caso do MPDF, uso:

```
$mpdf->Output($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/upload/pdf/'.$nomeArquivo.'.pdf', 'F');
```

Depois de gravado, pego o URL que gerei aí e uso o [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) para enviar o arquivo anexado. Para anexar algo com o PHPMailer, uso:

```
$mail->AddAttachment($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/upload/pdf/'.$nomeArquivo.'.pdf);
```

Comment: Muito obrigado Maykel! era dessa luz que eu precisava!! me ajudou bastante. Abraco!

Comment: Se conseguir, marque a resposta como respondida! ;-)