# Criar PDF com código PHP/HTML

Tags: php, pdf

Eu tenho uma página em HTML e PHP onde me mostra os dados todos de certas empresas.
O que quero agora fazer é criar um botão onde seja criado um PDF apenas com a informação em falta dessa empresa.

Quero criar em PDF pois acho que fica um pouco mais apresentável.

A minha duvida é:
Com PHP pode-se criar um PDF?

Comment: Sim, pode. Existem classes que fazem isso muito bem, como [`DOMPDF`](https://code.google.com/p/dompdf/wiki/Usage). Eu uso DOMPDF no Laravel 4 e, na minha opnião, é um ótimo recurso!

Comment: Uma outra ferramenta útil: http://www.fpdf.org/

Comment: Relacionado: [exportar uma página html/php para pdf](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/714/91)

Comment: Pode sim, com PHP pode criar um PDF.

Comment: Seja criado pelo PHP ou Software o que quero mesmo é poder organizar o PDF da maneira que eu quero. 
Pois cada empresa que irei inserir vai ser diferente uma da outra pois numa podem faltar 10 documentos outra faltar so um.