# Como exportar uma DIV inteira (com imagens, tabela e gráficos) para PDF?

Tags: javascript, html, css, pdf

Eu tenho uma DIV com diversos elementos ( imagens, tabela, gráficos) e preciso exportar essa DIV toda para PDF, eu tentei usar o plugin jsPDF mas não renderizou o CSS!!

Comment: Seria interessante postar o seu código para que possamos ajudar melhor você.

Comment: [nessa pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/714/13561) cada resposta indica uma ferramenta diferente, vale dar um conferida

Comment: entao meu codigo é uma tabela gerada dinamicamente, fica enorme com mais de 3000 linhas, agora preciso de um código que exporte essa div para PDF, já achei algo parecido, mas não renderiza o CSS.

Comment: eu uso uma lib php para esse trabalho, é o único modo! eu já usei [mPDF](http://www.mpdf1.com/mpdf/index.php)

Comment: nesse caso eu to trabalhando com java no backend, ja achei uma lib chamada itext mas ela não renderiza o CSS :/

Comment: se nao renderiza entao faz uma função que antes dele gerar o pdf ele pega o conteudo do arquivo css e joga numa tag <style> e poe no header da página

Comment: olha aqui: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12043035/html-to-pdf-using-itext-external-css

Comment: então cara pelo que eu vi ali ele também tava com esse problema, mais nenhuma solução serviu, acho que é impossivel fazer isso no backend por causa dos graficos, o mais correto seria fazer com javascript no front end