# Como exportar uma DIV HTML para PDF rederizando o CSS?

Tags: javascript, java, html, pdf

Alguem tem algum codigo que consiga exportar uma DIV para PDF renderizando todo o CSS dessa DIV? 
É melhor eu fazer isso no backEnd (Java) ou no frontEnd (JavaScript)?
Se alguem puder ajudar agradeço!!

EDIT:
Valeu pela resposta Gabriel Rodrigues, mas esse esquema ai não funfou do jeito que eu preciso[image: Olha como sai o PDF, ele não renderiza o CSS]

E a pagina original com css era assim:
[image: Print Original Pagina]

Comment: Acho que essa pergunta pode te ajudar: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/714/como-exportar-uma-p%C3%A1gina-html-php-para-pdf

Comment: Bem vindo ao StackOverflow, antes de formular uma pergunta, verifique se já existe uma resposta fazendo uma busca no site, se não, formule uma pergunta com bastante detalhes sobre seu problema.

Comment: @Geferson olha a tag java, esse link é referente as librarys de pdf para php, sergioBertolazo,  tem uma library chamada jsPDF mas ela não aceita css, você pode dar uma olhada tbm no html2canvas e usar os dois para uma solução.

Comment: Geferson essa solução de PHP nao vai servir no meu caso vlw!

Comment: Gabriel rodrigues, valeu pela resposta, eu ja tentei utilizar o plugin jsPDF mas ele não funcionou do jeito que eu precisei, ele só joga os dados da tabela não o CSS :/

Comment: @GabrielRodrigues Eu sei que o post era de php, mas isso não significa que a solução não possa estar lá, pois existem lib que tem versões tanto pra java,php e diversas outras linguagens, então antes de olhar simplesmente os tópicos e dizer que está errado, não custa dar uma olhada, inclusive as duas que você citou, está na pergunta mencionada.

Comment: Não tem como fazer isso via javascript, tem que ser no servidor mesmo. Existem muitos plugins que fazem isso... Mas dependendo das tags que o seu html tiver, alguns plugins podem aceitar e outros não... já tive muita dor de cabeça com isso

Comment: Valeu pela resposta Sérgio, eu tentei fazer utilizando itext no servidor, mas ele não renderiza o css, você conhece alguma outra bilioteca ?

Comment: Consegui só hoje apos mas de um ano, desde aquele dia eu to tentando.. só hoje consegui!!!! tem apenas um bugzinho mas jaja resolvo xD

Answer (score 13, accepted):

## Update

Baseado na seguinte [resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34934497/8802828), adaptei o `script` e criei uma [função estendida](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.fn.extend/) do `JQuery` para facilitar a criação de PDF's baseado em `HTML`. O script prove criar multiplicas páginas caso o tamanho da imagem ultrapasse o limite da folha a4, além de manter o `CSS` da página.

[Disponível também no gist](https://gist.github.com/matheustoseto/eca0002d538eed3d2b66e3d3abe05324).

```js
(function($){
    $.fn.createPdf = function(parametros) {
        
        var config = {              
            'fileName':'html-to-pdf'
        };
        
        if (parametros){
            $.extend(config, parametros);
        }                            

        var quotes = document.getElementById($(this).attr('id'));

        html2canvas(quotes, {
            onrendered: function(canvas) {
                var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'letter');

                for (var i = 0; i <= quotes.clientHeight/980; i++) {
                    var srcImg  = canvas;
                    var sX      = 0;
                    var sY      = 980*i;
                    var sWidth  = 900;
                    var sHeight = 980;
                    var dX      = 0;
                    var dY      = 0;
                    var dWidth  = 900;
                    var dHeight = 980;

                    window.onePageCanvas = document.createElement("canvas");
                    onePageCanvas.setAttribute('width', 900);
                    onePageCanvas.setAttribute('height', 980);
                    var ctx = onePageCanvas.getContext('2d');
                    ctx.drawImage(srcImg,sX,sY,sWidth,sHeight,dX,dY,dWidth,dHeight);

                    var canvasDataURL = onePageCanvas.toDataURL("image/png", 1.0);
                    var width         = onePageCanvas.width;
                    var height        = onePageCanvas.clientHeight;

                    if (i > 0) {
                        pdf.addPage(612, 791);
                    }

                    pdf.setPage(i+1);
                    pdf.addImage(canvasDataURL, 'PNG', 20, 40, (width*.62), (height*.62));
                }

                pdf.save(config.fileName);
            }
        });
    };
})(jQuery);
 

function createPDF() {
    $('#renderPDF').createPdf({
        'fileName' : 'testePDF'
    });
}
```

```html
<!-- import -->

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.4.1/jspdf.min.js"></script> 
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/canvas2image@1.0.5/canvas2image.min.js"></script>

<!-- import -->


<button type="button" class="btn btn-success" onclick="createPDF();">pdf</button>
 
<div id="renderPDF" class="container">
 <div class="jumbotron">
  <h1>Bootstrap Tutorial</h1>
  <p>Bootstrap is the most popular HTML, CSS, and JS framework for developing responsive, mobile-first projects on the web.</p>
 </div>
 <div id="customers">
  <table id="tab_customers" class="table table-striped">
   <thead>
    <tr class='btn-danger'>
     <th>#</th>
     <th>Population</th>
     <th>Date</th>
     <th>Age</th>
    </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
    <tr>
     <td>1</td>
     <td>1,363,480,000</td>
     <td>March 24, 2014</td>
     <td>19.1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>2</td>
     <td>1,241,900,000</td>
     <td>March 24, 2014</td>
     <td>17.4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>3</td>
     <td>317,746,000</td>
     <td>March 24, 2014</td>
     <td>4.44</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>4</td>
     <td>249,866,000</td>
     <td>July 1, 2013</td>
     <td>3.49</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>5</td>
     <td>201,032,714</td>
     <td>July 1, 2013</td>
     <td>2.81</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>6</td>
     <td>1,363,480,000</td>
     <td>March 24, 2014</td>
     <td>19.1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>7</td>
     <td>1,241,900,000</td>
     <td>March 24, 2014</td>
     <td>17.4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>8</td>
     <td>317,746,000</td>
     <td>March 24, 2014</td>
     <td>4.44</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>9</td>
     <td>249,866,000</td>
     <td>July 1, 2013</td>
     <td>3.49</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>10</td>
     <td>201,032,714</td>
     <td>July 1, 2013</td>
     <td>2.81</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>11</td>
     <td>1,363,480,000</td>
     <td>March 24, 2014</td>
     <td>19.1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>12</td>
     <td>1,241,900,000</td>
     <td>March 24, 2014</td>
     <td>17.4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>13</td>
     <td>317,746,000</td>
     <td>March 24, 2014</td>
     <td>4.44</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>14</td>
     <td>249,866,000</td>
     <td>July 1, 2013</td>
     <td>3.49</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>15</td>
     <td>201,032,714</td>
     <td>July 1, 2013</td>
     <td>2.81</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>16</td>
     <td>1,363,480,000</td>
     <td>March 24, 2014</td>
     <td>19.1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>17</td>
     <td>1,241,900,000</td>
     <td>March 24, 2014</td>
     <td>17.4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>18</td>
     <td>317,746,000</td>
     <td>March 24, 2014</td>
     <td>4.44</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>19</td>
     <td>249,866,000</td>
     <td>July 1, 2013</td>
     <td>3.49</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>20</td>
     <td>201,032,714</td>
     <td>July 1, 2013</td>
     <td>2.81</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>21</td>
     <td>1,363,480,000</td>
     <td>March 24, 2014</td>
     <td>19.1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>22</td>
     <td>1,241,900,000</td>
     <td>March 24, 2014</td>
     <td>17.4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>23</td>
     <td>317,746,000</td>
     <td>March 24, 2014</td>
     <td>4.44</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>24</td>
     <td>249,866,000</td>
     <td>July 1, 2013</td>
     <td>3.49</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>25</td>
     <td>201,032,714</td>
     <td>July 1, 2013</td>
     <td>2.81</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>26</td>
     <td>1,363,480,000</td>
     <td>March 24, 2014</td>
     <td>19.1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>27</td>
     <td>1,241,900,000</td>
     <td>March 24, 2014</td>
     <td>17.4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>28</td>
     <td>317,746,000</td>
     <td>March 24, 2014</td>
     <td>4.44</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>29</td>
     <td>249,866,000</td>
     <td>July 1, 2013</td>
     <td>3.49</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>30</td>
     <td>201,032,714</td>
     <td>July 1, 2013</td>
     <td>2.81</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>31</td>
     <td>1,363,480,000</td>
     <td>March 24, 2014</td>
     <td>19.1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>32</td>
     <td>1,241,900,000</td>
     <td>March 24, 2014</td>
     <td>17.4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>33</td>
     <td>317,746,000</td>
     <td>March 24, 2014</td>
     <td>4.44</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>34</td>
     <td>249,866,000</td>
     <td>July 1, 2013</td>
     <td>3.49</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>35</td>
     <td>201,032,714</td>
     <td>July 1, 2013</td>
     <td>2.81</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>36</td>
     <td>1,363,480,000</td>
     <td>March 24, 2014</td>
     <td>19.1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>37</td>
     <td>1,241,900,000</td>
     <td>March 24, 2014</td>
     <td>17.4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>38</td>
     <td>317,746,000</td>
     <td>March 24, 2014</td>
     <td>4.44</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>39</td>
     <td>249,866,000</td>
     <td>July 1, 2013</td>
     <td>3.49</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>40</td>
     <td>201,032,714</td>
     <td>July 1, 2013</td>
     <td>2.81</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>41</td>
     <td>1,363,480,000</td>
     <td>March 24, 2014</td>
     <td>19.1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>42</td>
     <td>1,241,900,000</td>
     <td>March 24, 2014</td>
     <td>17.4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>43</td>
     <td>317,746,000</td>
     <td>March 24, 2014</td>
     <td>4.44</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>44</td>
     <td>249,866,000</td>
     <td>July 1, 2013</td>
     <td>3.49</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>45</td>
     <td>201,032,714</td>
     <td>July 1, 2013</td>
     <td>2.81</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>46</td>
     <td>1,363,480,000</td>
     <td>March 24, 2014</td>
     <td>19.1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>47</td>
     <td>1,241,900,000</td>
     <td>March 24, 2014</td>
     <td>17.4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>48</td>
     <td>317,746,000</td>
     <td>March 24, 2014</td>
     <td>4.44</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>49</td>
     <td>249,866,000</td>
     <td>July 1, 2013</td>
     <td>3.49</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>50</td>
     <td>201,032,714</td>
     <td>July 1, 2013</td>
     <td>2.81</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>51</td>
     <td>1,363,480,000</td>
     <td>March 24, 2014</td>
     <td>19.1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>52</td>
     <td>1,241,900,000</td>
     <td>March 24, 2014</td>
     <td>17.4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>53</td>
     <td>317,746,000</td>
     <td>March 24, 2014</td>
     <td>4.44</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>54</td>
     <td>249,866,000</td>
     <td>July 1, 2013</td>
     <td>3.49</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>55</td>
     <td>201,032,714</td>
     <td>July 1, 2013</td>
     <td>2.81</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>56</td>
     <td>1,363,480,000</td>
     <td>March 24, 2014</td>
     <td>19.1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>57</td>
     <td>1,241,900,000</td>
     <td>March 24, 2014</td>
     <td>17.4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>58</td>
     <td>317,746,000</td>
     <td>March 24, 2014</td>
     <td>4.44</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>59</td>
     <td>249,866,000</td>
     <td>July 1, 2013</td>
     <td>3.49</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>60</td>
     <td>201,032,714</td>
     <td>July 1, 2013</td>
     <td>2.81</td>
    </tr>
   </tbody>
  </table>
 </div>
</div>
```

## ________________________________________________________

Utilizando as funções **jspdf** e **html2canvas** é possivel criar um PDF sem perder as propriedades do CSS.
Porém deve-se ficar atento ao fluxo da criação do pdf.

A ideia é criar uma imagem do html usando **html2canvas** e posteriormente usar a **hash**(imagem) criada para criar o pdf usando **jspdf**.

Como o formato padrão do pdf é no formato a4, temos que **redefinir** a largura da div para o formato a4 e após a criação do pdf, voltar ao **CSS** normal.

Primeiramente importar os js nessa ordem e após o jquery:

- 1º http://cdn.rawgit.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/dist/jspdf.min.js
- 2º    http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/build/html2canvas.js

Definir um **id** a div que será renderizada.

**Exemplo:**

```
<div id="renderPDF" class="container" style="background-color: #003399;">
  <h2>Basic Panel</h2>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-body">A Basic Panel</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Partindo para o JavaScript...**

```
 <script language="javascript"> 
        var cache_width = $('#renderPDF').width(); //Criado um cache do CSS
        var a4  =[ 595.28,  841.89]; // Widht e Height de uma folha a4

        function getPDF(){
        // Setar o width da div no formato a4
        $("#renderPDF").width((a4[0]*1.33333) -80).css('max-width','none');

        // Aqui ele cria a imagem e cria o pdf
        html2canvas($('#renderPDF'), {
          onrendered: function(canvas) {
            var img = canvas.toDataURL("image/png",1.0);  
            var doc = new jsPDF({unit:'px', format:'a4'});
            doc.addImage(img, 'JPEG', 20, 20);
            doc.save('NOME-DO-PDF.pdf');
            //Retorna ao CSS normal
            $('#renderPDF').width(cache_width);
          }
        });
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: Perfeito @Matheus. Para completar, se alguém precisar imprimir direto: doc.autoPrint();. +1

Comment: Esse jsPDF que você compartilhou não está mais atualizado. Pra quem estiver precisando pode usar esse aqui: https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.2.61/jspdf.min.js

Answer (score 3):

Da pra fazer umas solução boa juntando [jsPDF](https://parall.ax/products/jspdf) e [html2canvas](https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/)

**Exemplo:**

```js
$('#button').click(function() {
  var doc = new jsPDF('landscape', 'pt', 'a4');
  doc.addHTML($('#conteudo'), function() {
    doc.save("teste.pdf");
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
}
div {
  color: #605B5B;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 50px;
  margin: 10px;
}
button {
  background-color: #44c767;
  -moz-border-radius: 28px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 28px;
  border-radius: 28px;
  border: 1px solid #18ab29;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 17px;
  padding: 16px 31px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px #2f6627;
}
button:active {
  position: relative;
  top: 1px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/dist/jspdf.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/master/dist/html2canvas.js"></script>

<div id="conteudo">
  <h1>Silvio Santos Ipsum!</h1>
  <p>boca sujuam... sem vergonhuamm. Mah é a porta da esperançaam. O Raul Gil é gayam! ... Maa O Ah Ae! Ih Ih! O Raul Gil é gayamm! Mah é a porta da esperançaam.</p>
  <p>
    Patríciaaammmm... Luiz Ricardouaaammmmmm. Ha haeeee. Hi hi. É namoro ou amizadeemm? Ma vale dérreaisam? Eu só acreditoammmm.... Vendoammmm. Mah você não consegue né Moisés? Você não consegueam. Um, dois três, quatro, PIM, entendeuam? Ma vejam só, vejam
    só.
  </p>
</div>

<button id="button">Baixar</button>
```

Veja funcionando no [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gabrielr47/rLues6nk/63/)

Comment: Valeu pela resposta maninho, só que esse esquema não funcionou do jeito que eu preciso, ele não renderizou o css

Comment: Sai um fundo preto tipo tela de DOS correto? Se for, estou com o mesmo problema...