# Formatação CSS não aplica no plugin HTML2PDF

Tags: css

Estou usando o plugin [html2pdf](https://github.com/spipu/html2pdf/tree/master/doc), mas ao tentar usar a formatação `CSS`:

> table { line-height: 10px }

A mesma não é aplicada, não achei nada na documentação do plugin, alguém sabe como arrumar isso?

Exemplo do que faz o `CSS` "`table { line-height: 10px }`"

```css
table { line-height: 10px }
```

```html
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th>
    <th>Age</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Realmente o html2pdf tem diversas limitações quanto ao uso de css, você pode verificar realmente se é o caso de uma dessas limitações, ai suas opções seriam:

- Criar um issue no [repositório oficial](https://github.com/spipu/html2pdf/issues) do projeto;
- Caso for urgente, criar um fork do projeto e identificar e resolver o problema (não se esqueça de criar um Pull-request no projeto original se conseguir hehe);
- Testar uma solução com JavaScript, usando pdf.js e html2canvas, como descrito mostrado [nessa questão](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/119821/como-exportar-uma-div-html-para-pdf-rederizando-o-css).

Espero ter ajudado em algo  :)

Comment: Pois é, pensei na terceira opção, mas da maneira que foi feito a programação me parece não aceitar javascript, somente php, daí terei que fazer uma baita gambi, vou tentar fazer com javascript, se não der, terei que apelar para a segunda opção mesmo :|