# Gerar um PDF a partir de uma Div HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, vb.net

Boa Noite pessoal...

Gostaria de saber oque posso usar para gerar um Pdf a partir de uma div selecionada.

Poderia ser em Jquery,VB,Vb net Ou Javascript.

Poderiam me ajudar ?

Answer (score -1):

Cara eu faco da seguinte forma.

eu pego o elemento (id ou class) e coloco o evento de (CTRL + P) que abre a opcao de imprimir a pagina ou salvar como pdf.

ou

Vc vai ter que pegar o elemento e transformar em um canvas.

-> [Como exportar uma DIV HTML para PDF rederizando o CSS?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/119821/como-exportar-uma-div-html-para-pdf-rederizando-o-css)

http://cdn.rawgit.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/dist/jspdf.min.js
http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/build/html2canvas.js